# Comando switch sendo executado mesmo sem ser chamado - C

Tags: c

Estou resolvendo um exercício de lógica e não consigo entender o erro:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
int TotalVinhos=0, t=0, b=0, r=0, fim = 0;
//float Porc;
char tipo;

while(fim == 0){
  printf("Tipo do vinho: ");
  scanf("%c", &tipo);

switch(tipo){
    case 'T':
        t++;
        TotalVinhos++;
        break;
    case 'B':
        b++;
        TotalVinhos++;
        break;
    case 'R':
        r++;
        TotalVinhos++;
        break;
    case 'F':
        fim = 1;
        break;
    default:
        printf("erro..");
        break;
  }

}

 printf("Total de vinhos: %d\n", TotalVinhos);
 printf("Quantida de vinho tipo T: %d\n", t);
 printf("Quantida de vinho tipo B: %d\n", b);
 printf("Quantida de vinho tipo R: %d", r); 
}
```

O erro que me é apresentado:

[image: Ele executa 2x e já da a opção default]

Comment: Esse código nem compila, pelo menos em compilador decente. Inclusive esse código não pode dar o resultado apresentado. Se você posta um código e está usando outro fica complicado ajudar.

Comment: Qual compilador é descente?

Comment: @bigown veja, alterei o código.. agora é pra compilar porém mantem o erro ali

Comment: Piorou. Tem que postar algo que você sabe que pelo menos está compilando.

Comment: Arrumei os erros, deu uma organizada, mas mantive a essência do código e está funcionando. http://ideone.com/ohtaSe

Comment: Eu testei o código que arrumei agora no repl.it e rodou porém com o erro

Comment: O código que você postou também está com o mesmo erro:

Comment: Não pra mim https://i.stack.imgur.com/lX9ri.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Um array de char termina com `\0` então criei com tamanho 2 (um para o caractere e um para o `\0`). Na hora de passar o valor para o case, passei só o tipo[0], que é o valor necessário.
Mudei também o `bool` porque não havia nenhum include para o tipo `bool` no código. Substitui por int com 1 e 0 que funciona da mesma forma.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int TotalVinhos=0, t=0, b=0, r=0;
    //float Porc;
    int fim=1;
    char tipo[2];

    do
    {
        printf("Tipo do vinho: ");
        scanf("%s", &tipo);

        switch(tipo[0])
        {
        case 'T':
            t++;
            TotalVinhos++;
            break;
        case 'B':
            b++;
            TotalVinhos++;
            break;
        case 'R':
            r++;
            TotalVinhos++;
            break;
        case 'F':
            fim = 0;
            break;
        default:
            printf("erro..");
            break;
        }

    }
    while(fim);

    printf("Total de vinhos: %d\n", TotalVinhos);
    printf("Quantida de vinho tipo T: %d\n", t);
    printf("Quantida de vinho tipo B: %d\n", b);
    printf("Quantida de vinho tipo R: %d", r);
}
```

Não sei se há algum outro modo de fazer, mas assim está funcionando corretamente.

Comment: Bom funcionou, só não entendi porque no switch você coloca "tipo[0]"

Comment: Porque é a posição que está o caractere que você recebeu, ( a outra "tipo[1]" está com o "\0"). Já editei  a resposta com uma explicação curta do que foi alterado.

Comment: Por exemplo, se eu recebi um 'T' no scanf, a variável tipo será: tipo = ['T', '/0']